# Database design to avoid redundancy issue: use a convention or different design?

Tags: oop, database-design

**Note:** Images are clickable to allow zoom

I have problem with this database design, I have different solution but none of them satisfact me enough.

The software is about a configurator for a product. You can choose with this configurator all the extras that will increase the price.

[image: Package with price]

[image: Package without price]

This is the data that I should present to the user. What's giving me problems is the fact that there are 2 type of extras:

1. This type of extra doesn't have a price, is merged inside a *package* which has a price for all its extras. (Relax [A123] is an example of package with price, first image)
2. This type of extra has a price and its package doesn't have any price, because they aren't boundled in the package (Water supply is an example of package without price)

Here is my current design, which I'm not satisfact with:

[image: Database design]

(Ignore *ExtrasCategory* which is only to group up extras)

The biggest problem is that each Extra (the class now) belongs to a package, even if it doesn't have a price.

However, each Package may have a price different for each Boat, so I need to set different prices.

I want something like this:

- Each Extra has a "basic" Package.
- If the Package has a price, we set it differently for each boat
- If the Package doesn't have a price, we can use the "basic" Package of the Extra

However in this way I have redundancy: Extra has a Package, BoatExtra (an extra with price) has a BoatExtrasPackage and so we have 2 times a reference to a package

How can I solve this design issue?

**Edit 1:** Ok I've created an image which explains better what I want. I want a "default package" for an extra (on a per-extra basis), if the BoatExtra doesn't have one.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems the problem is that I want to minimize space consumption, not make a good design. After I understood I were doing this (which for me it's wrong) I came up with a totally different design which is better than the previous one and fixed my problem.

I obviusly need to build more packages but this is what the logic wants

[image: Database structure fixed]

Answer (score 0):

You have redundancy in your design ie: code and name. I would do it as attached if I understand properly your system.[image]

Comment: I can't read that part on left... damn. If I understood you are suggesting to assing the "package" as a string, which could be a good idea. If you are talking about category and package, then they are 2 different names (well they both have <name> btw)

Comment: I updated to show better what I want, I'm watching your image now. **EDIT** no category and package are 2 different thing. Ignore category at the moment, there isn't a problem of redundancy in that way. The problem is that I link 2 times the Package (watch the edit in question).

Comment: OK then ignore my image. You can have package that link to itself if it's not basic.

Comment: **That's interesting** let me think a bit about it!